# Rails App cant deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

Im currenty using **AWS** with **OpsWork**
for my **Ruby On Rails App**
I am bit a confused about how we handle deployment in **OpsWork**
We are using Bitbucket.

I have serval instances, but we cannot fetch the git repo.

So my question is :

Should I add deployment keys in bitbucket for all the instances I have running so we it wont throw me this error?.

Or is there another place in this is done?!

*(Im using Chef, Nginx & Unicorn)*

```
[2015-05-12T08:45:55+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2015-05-12T08:45:55+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-05-12T08:45:55+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-05-12T08:45:55+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-05-12T08:45:55+00:00] ERROR: git[Download Custom Cookbooks] (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 29) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/cookbooks.git" HEAD ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: conq: repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```